# Custom message in Simple Data Writer

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests

i am using jmeter. I want to use two components: Simple Date Writer. One for success and one for error.

I wonder (I can't find it in the internet) how to attach my own message to the saving file?
For example:
On Success: "YOU ARE THE BEST"
On Error: "Something wrong"

I know, I can add many details about respons to the file, but i need custom message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can amend response message based on the condition using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) language, something like:

```
if (prev.isSuccessful()) {
    prev.setResponseMessage('YOU ARE THE BEST')
}
else {
    prev.setResponseMessage('Something wrong')
}
```

[image]

In the above example `prev` stands for the [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class instance, see JavaDoc for all available functions and properties and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) article to learn more about various JMeter API shorthands available for [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

In this case you can configure the Simple Data Writer to save the response message:

[image]

and enjoy the custom message in the result file.

Comment: Thank you! :) I'm using JDBC Request and surely can't I use `prev`?

Answer (score 1):

Flexible File Writer Plugin might help you. https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin/

if not then you can open simple data writer results in excel and use conditioning formatting for your requirement.
Hope this might help you.